# Secure Websocket (wss / TLS) behind router failing

Tags: php, javascript, websocket, router, stunnel

I just want to preface this question by saying that I have most of this working but that I've been scouring the internet for days trying to find documentation for this one piece of the puzzle.

Here's my stack:

```
- Router port forwarding (80,443,8080)
- Laptop (DHCP)
- stunnel (443 -> 8080)
- websocket (8080)
```

Router port forwarding:

```
TCP 80, 443, 8080 -> 192.168.1.x
```

Laptop firewall:

```
sudo ipfw add allow tcp from any to any 443
```

Stunnel:

```
[https]
accept  = 443
connect = 8080
```

Websocket binding:

```
('0.0.0.0', 8080);
```

Client:

```
ws://hostname:8080/
wss://hostname:443/
```

Here's what's working so far:

`When connecting from my computer: Both secure wss and non secure websocket connections succeed. The websocket reports that I've connected from 127.0.0.1.`

What is not working:

`When connecting from my phone via 3g (outside my router): Non secure works, secure does not.`

Chrome, Safari, nor Firefox provide ***any*** debugging for Websocket connections so I have no idea what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated.

Zach

Comment: I am having a similar problem, my issue was due to my bad upload rate, as well as some issues with safari on my iphone.

For your problem make sure to do a port forwarding in your router, so that when he gets a requests on a port like 8080 he will redirect it to your pc (inside your network) on the same port (which is 8080)